# Having trouble running "mate .rspec"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line, rspec

I'm trying to run `mate .rspec` in my command prompt in order to open the .rspec configuration file. However, I get the error `-bash: mate: command not found`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Though [Brandon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113420/having-trouble-running-mate-rspec/5113455#5113455) is correct, there's a far simpler way to set up the `mate` command through TextMate itself.

In the menu bar, select Help > Terminal Usage..., choose `/usr/bin` from the dropdown, and it will create the link for you.

You *might* have to open a new Terminal window for it to take effect, but then you should be all set.

Comment: Gah! It's in the HELP menu! I checked *everywhere* else. I had eventually concluded that it (rather stupidly) only prompted you the first time you started the application.

Comment: This is definitely the way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

**[Update]**

[T.J.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113420/having-trouble-running-mate-rspec/5113698#5113698) is much better than mine. :)

**[Original Answer]**

TextMate installs the `mate` command to  `/usr/local/bin/mate`. First, I would check to see if the `mate` command is in that directory:

```
ls -lah /usr/local/bin/mate
```

If you get `ls: /usr/local/bin/mate: No such file or directory`, then you can install the `mate` command by creating a symbolic link to the binary, which lives in the TextMate.app folder:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/mate /usr/local/bin/mate
```

At this point, you should be able to run `mate` from the command line.

If you got output other than `No such file or directory` from the `ls` command, it means that `/usr/local/bin` is not on your path.

Comment: thanks, but exactly how do I "create a symbolic link to the binary?"

Comment: Using the command under that sentence: `sudo ln -s /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/mate /usr/local/bin/mate`